# How do I initialize the parent class using a class method instead of calling the constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have class A which I want to inherit from, this class has a class method that can initialize a new instance from some data. I don't have access to the code for `from_data` and can't change the implementation of A.

I want to initialize new instances of class B using the same data I would pass to the A's `from_data` method. In the solution I came up with I create a new instance of A in  `__new__(...)` and change the `__class__` to B. `__init__(...)` can then further initialize the "new instance of B" as normal. It seems to work but I'm not sure this will have some sort of side effects.

So will this work reliably? Is there a proper way of achieving this?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, alpha, beta):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data):
        obj = cls(*data)
        return obj


class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, data):
        a = A.from_data(data)
        a.__class__ = cls
        return a

    def __init__(self, data):
        pass


b = B((5, 3))
print(b.alpha, b.beta)
print(type(b))
print(isinstance(b, B))
```

Output:

```
5 3
<class '__main__.B'>
True
```

Comment: Even if it does work reliably, it's going to confuse everybody who ever uses your code. Do you really mean for `B` to inherit from `A`? Consider having `B` *contain* an `A`. Then you can initialize it however you like, and no one will question it.

Comment: `a.__class__ = cls` is just hacky. Why do this at all? Why implement `__new__` to begin with? Why not just use `B.from_data((5, 3))`....?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The problem with is that since B woudn't inherit from A, something like `isinstance(b, A)` would return `False`, instead of `True`. Which is what I need in this case. I need to pass B objects into fuctions taking and checking for A.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `B.from_data()`, and getting rid of your `__new__()`?  If the implementation of `A.from_data()` is at all like what you show, that should work just fine.

Comment: In that case, I'm inclined to agree with Jason. Why do you need a separate class at all? What does `B` do that `A` can't? An initializer is the minimum work necessary to get a class up and running, so failing to run that roughly means that your `A` isn't a very good `A` (assuming a well-designed API, that is)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @jasonharper Yea I thought of that, but I don't have the code for `from_data`. So I can't re-implement it for B. I need to call `A.from_data`

Comment: Why would you need to reimplement it?  You're already inheriting it.

Comment: @jasonharper it returns an instance of A. I need to change it to an instance of B. Which is what I'm doing here with the hacky `a.__class__ = cls`. This is the part I have my doubts with. Not much the `__new__`. I can indeed move it to a classmethod as well.

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns an instance of `cls`, where `cls` is whatever class you called it on. That's the advantage of `classmethod` over `staticmethod` in Python.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Interesting, thanks. I'll try that out.

Comment: @AarondeWindt **no you don't**. Just do `b = B.from_data((5, 3))`. Try it for yourself (after ommiting that `__new__` implementation)

Comment: Thanks @SilvioMayolo, it works. I was overthinking this a bit too much.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yea I just tried it. thaanks

Comment: Hypothetical now, that doesn't apply to my current problem. What if B takes in more parameters to initialize than data? I guess overloading and calling super().from_data should work right?

Comment: I just tried and it seems `super` works just fine from class methods. Though, again, I would urge caution in using too much non-standard trickery in your code. These questions are super fun to entertain as a hypothetical, but in real code, remember the KISS principle.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I avoid these things myself as much as possible. In this case, I've just been pushed into a hidden proprietary code corner.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your use-case is more abstract than I am understanding, but testing out in a REPL, it seems that calling the parent `class A` constructor via `super()`

```py
class A:
    # ...


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(*data)


b = B((5, 3))
print(b.alpha, b.beta)
print(type(b))
print(isinstance(b, B))
```

also results in

```py
5 3
<class '__main__.B'>
True
```

Is there a reason you don't want to call `super()` to instantiate a new instance of your child class?

---

**Edit:**

So, in case you *need* to use the `from_data` constructor... you could do something like

```py
#... class A

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, data):
        a_obj = A.from_data(data)
        for attr in a_obj.__dict__:
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(a_obj, attr))
```

That is *really* hacky though... and not guaranteed to work for all attrs of `A` class object, especially if the `__dict__` function has been overloaded.